# Criando EF Designer a partir de um banco de dados

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em NEXT ele fecha, quando eu utilizo um banco *sqlserver* ele funciona normalmente, mas neste caso estou tentando com *mysql* e estou com este problema, fiz várias modificações nos *plugins*, referencia e não deu certo.

Já aconteceu algo parecido com vocês?

Comment: Qual a versão do visual studio? já tentou remover e instalar novamente o provider do mysql ?

Comment: esse problema realmente é causa por versão do provider e as demais referencias, eu removi e fiz a instalação novamente porém em uma versão mais antiga compativel com meu projeto. esta tudo certo!

Answer (score 0):

esse problema realmente é causa por versão do provider e as demais referencias, eu removi e fiz a instalação novamente porém em uma versão mais antiga compativel com meu projeto. esta tudo certo!

PS: Só pra deixar no padrão da comunidade, após tanto tempo. foi mal kkk

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.